# Irreducible projective representations of finite abelian groups

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

I want to know if there is a description of all irreducible complex projective representations of an arbitrary finite abelian group. I have seen this for particular cases such as those given [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/glasgow-mathematical-journal/article/some-projective-representations-of-finite-abelian-groups/3B93CBB53A049E0D2BB630965303CC9D) and [here](https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-pdf/s2-7/2/235/2596951/s2-7-2-235.pdf). I am not able to find any literature for the general case.